# Windows 7 - Blue screens, fresh install, corrupt downloads

Tags: windows-7, memory, bsod, network-adapter

I'll clarify the title. I had a Windows 7 Ultimate installation running just fine about 2 months ago, aside from the fact that I would get BSOD's (Blue Screen of Death) every 2 weeks or so. I wanted to dual boot to Ubuntu, but I messed up my partition and ended up fresh installing Windows.

This fresh install of Windows was installed about 3 weeks ago, but then I started noticing weird behaviour. Downloads would hang or fail, some programs didn't work like they used to, whatever. I installed fresh again (about 2 days ago) and now everything is f****d up for a lack of a better word.

I can install my NIC driver for my Asus PCE-N15 just fine, but when I download things such as display drivers, it tells me the file is corrupt. I thought this was because my internet was messed up but downloading the **exact same package** on another computer on my network and transferring it to my computer via USB worked just fine.

When I try to download an update for Steam, the download bar keeps resetting and the logs tell me its because the checksums are messed up.

However, I am able to use Google Chrome on this computer to access the internet so it can't be my internet can it?

The most reasonable prognosis I can give is that my RAM is shot; I had it overclocked for awhile but it hasn't been OC'd for almost half a year now. However, the BSOD's from before, the corrupt downloads, and incorrect checksums when downloading Steam's updates all point to corrupt memory.

So I ran `mdsched.exe`... and the memory was fine. If it's not the memory then is my motherboard shot? Is my installation disk messed up?

Has anybody had a problem like this in the past?

Comment: There is something wrong with the laptop's network connection. Possibly a corrupt driver install. Very unlikely to be RAM, you would notice other issues. The clue is in the download problems. Try downloading a new copy of the network driver, delete the driver using device manager, reboot then rediscover the hardware and reinstall the driver.

Comment: How would I be able to access the internet if it was my NIC?

Comment: Just because there is something wrong doesn't mean that you cannot access it at all. Networks are designed to be highly resilient to problems but corrupted larger downloads is typical of a misconfigured or otherwise damaged network connection (it could also be a wiring issue).

Comment: Well I've downloaded my network driver on another computer and transferred via USB, so the problem can't be the driver... Do you think it could be the hardware? I'll try Ethernet to see if that's the problem for sure.

Comment: But did you delete and reinstall?

Comment: @JulianKnight you were right, I hooked up to ethernet and everything worked. Write an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Done, glad  I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with the laptop's network connection. Possibly a corrupt driver install.

It is very unlikely to be RAM, you would notice other issues. The clue is in the download problems.

Try downloading a new copy of the network driver, delete the driver using device manager, reboot then rediscover the hardware and reinstall the driver.

Note that just because there is something wrong doesn't mean that you cannot access it at all. Networks are designed to be highly resilient to problems but corrupted larger downloads is typical of a misconfigured or otherwise damaged network connection (it could also be a wiring issue).

Comment: Thanks again, Ethernet worked so it was a faulty NIC. I'll send it in for an RMA.